# Ubuntu boots to tty1

Tags: tty

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 and it was working but then i rebooted and now it boots to a command line that says tty1 if i press control alt f1 - f8 it goes to tty1 - tty8.  How do I fix this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply run the below command on tty,

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```