# Ubuntu 14.04.4 (GNOME) Boots to tty1

Tags: boot, gnome, tty

First, I have seen [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/450869/ubuntu-boots-to-tty1) and also [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/546601/ubuntu-14-04-boots-to-tty1) regarding the matter, but none really helped me. I ran regular updates on a *fresh* Ubuntu GNOME 14.04 install, added Texlive 2015, LibreOffice 5.1, Steam and Dropbox. I have also removed Evolution and installed Thunderbird, it worked fine, I used the computer yesterday as always and when I started it up today, it would take me to the TTY1 boot, which I know nothing about. Here's an image:

[tt1 screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Ne68.jpg)

Some other forums suggested editing the boot option in the grub menu by pressing `E` over the ubuntu option. Here's an image of what I see when I do that:

[Editing the Grub Option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOWpS.jpg)

A few users mentioned adding `nomodset`where I see `quiet splash` (2nd to last line), others suggested replacing one with another. Neither worked. To be honest, I am out of patience. I'd like to avoid reinstalling Ubuntu, as installing a whole TeX environment on it, re-add my e-mail, updates, and software would take too long. Noob-friendly answers are much prefered!

Comment: can you get the desktop from tt1 using `startx`

Comment: No, but it gave me a kinda lengthy message [here](http://i.imgur.com/T7Nweh3.jpg).

Comment: Do u have free space in your hard disk ? find it out by using `df -h`

Comment: @MohitRajan I have free space. It is a fresh installation, too

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of the xorg log. Also mention your graphic card

Answer (score 0):

After following links on the subject (a long time ago), I ended up (somehow) installing unity over gnome, which obviously messed everything up. I had to format the computer and reinstall Ubuntu. Now, it works.